# Data connection between program in PC and nativescript app in PHONE

Tags: c++, json, database, nativescript

Im guessing how to provide connection between PC and PHONE.

I need to transfer some values between. They could be stored in DB, json file or something.

And the problem is that the values should be refreshing quite often, minimum 30 sec.

So program in PC will update data every 30 sec and then make changes in DB or in file and then MOBILE app will read this data. Cycle could be occured in reverse too.

it will look like this:

```
'user': $user,
'points': $points,
'actual_value1': $actual_value1,
'actual_value2': $actual_value2,
'map-position': $map position
```

SO my question is what is the best way to achieve this connection?

- I thought about firebase, but there is limit in connection in free
  version if we think in scaling in future.
- maybe just write/read json file from ftp?
- mysql db would be appropiate too?

records/data will be updated every 30 seconds so how it looks with database query and performance?
there will be no problem with so often changing values in db?
How it seems compared to uploading ftp json file and reading it?

whats the best solution for data connection between these two apps?

Comment: What is your transport method? Local, cloud, other?

Comment: data should be available from anywhere not only in local connection. I want control PC app using my MOBILE app. so data must be stored somewhere in web. db, ftp, cloud etc

Comment: Firebase sounds fine to me. You'll likely have to pay a price to scale any system, which should be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want data to be available in any device (PC / Mobile), it has to be on cloud. So Firebase is the easiest option where you don't have to worry about your backend infrastructure but yes of course you have to pay when you scale it.

Or you may build your own backend application, probably with NodeJS and use sockets to transmit data whenever there is a change.